# Python 3.5 TypeError: got multiple values for argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, args, optional-arguments

```
def f(a, b, *args):
    return (a, b, args)

f(a=3, b=5)  
(3, 5, ())
```

whereas:

```
f(a=3, b=5, *[1,2,3])  
TypeError: got multiple values for argument 'b'
```

Why it behaves like this?
Any particular reason?

Comment: Interesting, the exception gives "got multiple values for keyword argument 'a'" in python 2.7 and  "got multiple values for argument 'b'" in python 3.5

Comment: @cdarke When using keyword arguments what happens is that python builds a `dict` to store those arguments. `dict`s don't have a reliable order. The difference in the error message reflects this: using python2.7 it happens that the hash make so that `a` is the first key to be iterated over while on python3.5 it happens to `b`. But it completely depends on how the dictionary is built etc.

Comment: @Bakuriu:  I was aware of that, but I feel there should have been some effort to get a consistent and helpful error message, regardless of the internal implementation.  The "real" problem is using keywords before positional arguments, and that's the error that should have been detected and reported.

Comment: @cdarke So you would like to get a `SyntaxError` whenever that syntax is used? This is inconsistent with most of python, where most errors are raised at runtime. Moreover there are cases where such calls would be fine, e.g. `f(a=3, b=5, *[])` isn't a problem. Also in the general case `f(**kwargs, *args)` is still fine if the arguments in `kwargs` and those in `args` don't overlap. Finally: python can never be sure which function is actually going to be called, so it's impossible to decide a priori if there is an overlap or not.

Answer (score 8):

In the documentation [for calls:](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls)

> If the syntax `*expression` appears in the function call, expression must evaluate to an iterable. Elements from these iterables are treated as if they were additional positional arguments. For the call `f(x1, x2, *y, x3, x4)`, if `y` evaluates to a sequence `y1, ..., yM`, this is equivalent to a call with `M+4` positional arguments `x1, x2, y1, ..., yM, x3, x4`.

And, this is followed by:

> *A consequence of this is that although the `*expression` syntax may appear after explicit keyword arguments, it is processed **before** the keyword arguments* (and any `**expression arguments` – see below).

(emphasis mine)

So Python will first process the `*args` as positional arguments, assign a value to `b` and re-assign it with `b=5` resulting in an error for the keyword argument having multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the keywords.  You are not allowed positional arguments after keyword arguments.

```
f(3, 5, *[1,2,3])
```

works fine, in that it passes a *tuple* with the values 1,2,3.  The same as:

```
f(3, 5, *(1,2,3))
```

Keywords must always come after positional arguments, so it is your function declaration which is incorrect:

```
def f(*args, a, b):
    return (a, b, args)

print(f(a=3, b=5))
print(f(*[1,2,3], a=3, b=5))
```

Gives:

```
(3, 5, ())
(3, 5, (1, 2, 3))
```